# After creation hook

Tags: javascript, mongoose

Let's say I have a mongoose model `m`.

This model `m` was created with a Schema `s` that adds a method to log things:

```
s.methods.log = function(s) {
  this.theLogger(s);
}
```

theLogger must be feed at any time, so I feed theLogger at postinit hook.

This works:

```
const x = await m.findOne({_id: ...});
x.log("something");
```

The problem here is that this won't work:

```
const x = new m();
x.log("something"); // <--- theLogger is not defined.
```

Is there any way to hook the moment `x` is created using `new` operator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I still don't know if these hooks exist, so I finally solved this by extending the model using a function:

```
return ((parent) => {
    function HookedModel(a, b) {
        // Pre new hooks here <-----
        this.constructor = parent;
        parent.call(this, a, b);
        // Post new  hooks here <-----
    }
    // Copy all static functions:
    for (const k in parent) {
        if (parent.hasOwnProperty(k)) {
            HookedModel[k] = parent[k];
        }
    }
    HookedModel.__proto__ = parent.__proto__;
    HookedModel.prototype = Object.create(parent.prototype);
    HookedModel.prototype.constructor = HookedModel;
    return HookedModel;
})(model);
```